# Eigenvalues less than or equal to 1

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What proprieties does a square $n\times n$ real matrix $\mathbf M$ need to have in order to have all it's eigenvalues be less than or equal to one in absolute value?

I'm looking for proprieties such as "Have all it's elements be less than one" or "The sum of the squares of it's columns have to add up to one or less" or similar proprieties.

[Note: I am not claiming these examples to be true, I am using them merely as demonstrations of the kind proprieties I am looking for]

Much appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for necessary conditions or sufficient conditions?

Comment: Any conditions would help, really.

Comment: Are you talking about real or complex matrices? For real matrices, the condition is much weaker, because it doesn't have to have eigenvalues at all (if $n$ is even).

Comment: Real Matrices. I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks - brain failure

Comment: @MarkBennet, I imagine you are preoccupied with the situation in  Crimea.

Comment: Have you heard of the [Gershgorin's circle theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem)? That should answer your question.

Comment: Is there an adjective to describe a matrix in which all eigenvalues are abs < 1? so that raised to higher powers it goes to zero? 'diminishing?'

Answer (score 4):

Instead of summing the squares of elements in a column or row, sum the absolute values of the elements in a row. if this is less than 1 for each row, you have it. Same for columns. these correspond to [induced norms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Induced_norm),

Comment: So ANY matrix that respects this will have $\lambda_i\leq 1$?

Comment: well, $|\lambda_i|$ in case they are complex. But yes.